# Print Up to 300 Strings of Arrays to PDF Based on a Calculated Value

Tags: excel, vba

I need to print a string of arrays dependent on a difference of two values on my input page to separate sheets within the same PDF but I have been running into a few issues.

Based on the difference of two cells, the function will determine which arrays to print.

There are two possible solutions I have thought of but have been unsuccessful attempting both.

1. Indirectly reference a string of arrays in a cell to print such as "abc,bcd,cde,def,efg..."
2. (As Shown Below) Use conditional if-then functions to invoke the array based on the difference in these two cells

#### Primary Goals

1. Print into a single PDF
2. Determine specific arrays to print depending on the difference in two values contained in a cell on my input page
3. Allow for PageSetup values (have this figured out)

I am using MSFT 365.  I tried initially using an indirect array reference to a cell with a variable value string including the arrays to be included without success.

Next, I tried to hardcode for all 100 possible values for this difference but in that case, I am running into line limits and errors associated with using _ to continue the array function on another line.

If the difference value equals 3, it is shown as below.  If the difference value equals 4, you would add another array line including "schedule05","report05","p&l05"

```
Option Explicit

Sub PrintTest()

'if a certain difference value, use
If (Worksheets("Inputs").Range("D7") - Worksheets("Inputs").Range("D6")) = "3" Then


Dim pageArray As Variant

'set array for given difference
pageArray = Array("schedule01", "report01", "p&l01", _
"schedule02", "report02", "p&l02", _
"schedule03", "report03", "p&l03", _
"schedule04", "report04", "p&l04")


Worksheets("data").Activate
Worksheets("data").PageSetup.CenterHorizontally = True

'page setup values
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
.FitToPagesWide = 1
.FitToPagesTall = 1
.Orientation = xlLandscape
End With

'call array for print
Worksheets("data").Range("pageArray").PrintOut

Elseif

'Here is where I could put another similar function for a difference of 4


'......

Else
'Here is where I could put another similar function for a difference of x

End If
End Sub
```

I expected this would get me a PDF where each of these arrays is printed on a separate sheet and will print a selection of arrays based on the difference value.

Comment: Is it always `print all [schedule<=(diff+1)]","[report<=(diff+1)]","[p&l<=(diff+1)]` ?  So if diff is 4, it would gather schedule01 through schedule05 (and same for the rest)?

Comment: Yes, it would be.  The arrays are report01 through report100 and likewise for p&l and schedule.  I would also like to include additional summaries of report, p&l, and schedule which would be consolidated and included under all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment, it would look like this:

```
Dim lDiff As Long
Dim pageArray As Variant
Dim sFormat As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long

'if a certain difference value, use
lDiff = Worksheets("Inputs").Range("D7").Value - Worksheets("Inputs").Range("D6").Value
ReDim pageArray(1 To (lDiff + 1) * 3)
For i = 1 To UBound(pageArray, 1) Step 3
    j = j + 1
    If j < 100 Then sFormat = "00" Else sFormat = "000"
    pageArray(i) = "schedule" & Format(j, sFormat)
    pageArray(i + 1) = "report" & Format(j, sFormat)
    pageArray(i + 2) = "p&l" & Format(j, sFormat)
    MsgBox pageArray(i)
Next i
```

Comment: Under this scenario, how would you include the PrintOut function to send to PDF?

Comment: @mj11314256 You didn't show your code for that.  I assume it would be the same as what you're doing now where you loop through every element in your array.

Comment: Worksheets("data").Range("pageArray").PrintOut in the original code popped up the save as PDF print function.  When this is run, I still obtain an "Application-define or object-defined error".

Comment: Ah, ok, that's expecting a one-dimensional array instead of 2 dimensional like I have here.  Just need to change how the array is generated.  Just a sec

Comment: Thank you tigeravatar, appreciate the help

Comment: I'm still not getting a functioning PrintOut.  For the message box, it also only is showing the Schedule values.

Comment: The msgbox was just for testing, that can be removed.

Comment: I understand that.  I am still receiving the same errors as before running this macro.

Comment: I find it surprising that your original code would work and this does not since they are functionally the same. May need to `Join` the array into a comma delimited string (or build it as a comma delimited string to begin with)

Comment: My original code was not working to print the PDF that's why I posted.  It worked when the array's were short and did not have to go to multiple lines.

Comment: I appreciate you trying it out tigeravatr